# iOS Sliding Animation Happens Twice Unwantingly

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, core-animation

I'm working on a page-based iPhone app using Xcode 4.4 with ARC and have been stuck on this for awhile. On a certain page, a UIImageView finger needs to slide up and point to something and then slide left off the screen. This works as expected when I run it once, but when I turn the page and go back - there is now 2 fingers sliding about 0.5 seconds out of sync with eachother.

Here's the code:

```
-(void)fingerSwipeUp:(UIImageView *)imageView
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(213.75,355.5)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)fingerSwipeLeft:(UIImageView *)imageView
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(-80,355.5)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

UIImageView *finger = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"finger.png"]];

// position finger off the screen
[finger setFrame:CGRectMake(142.5,480,152.5,243)];
[self.view addSubview:finger];

[self performSelector:@selector(fingerSwipeUp:) withObject:finger afterDelay:6];
[self performSelector:@selector(fingerSwipeLeft:) withObject:finger afterDelay:8];
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: where u r allocating & adding finger image...?

Comment: where are you calling this[self performSelector:@selector(fingerSwipeUp:) withObject:finger afterDelay:6];
[self performSelector:@selector(fingerSwipeLeft:) withObject:finger afterDelay:8];

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you're creating the "finger" view in ViewDidAppear()?  If that's the case, every time the page is turned (hidden) and then gone back to, you're adding another arrow (subview).  What about this instead:

```
if (finger == nil) {
    finger = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"finger.png"]];
    [finger setFrame:CGRectMake(142.5,480,152.5,243)];
    [self.view addSubview:finger];
}

[self performSelector:@selector(fingerSwipeUp:) withObject:finger afterDelay:6];
[self performSelector:@selector(fingerSwipeLeft:) withObject:finger afterDelay:8];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a number of animations in a sequence, you might find it easier to use the block-based `UIView` animation syntax:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:6.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

    // animation 1

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:8.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

        // animation 2
    }];

}];
```

This will only start animation 2 *after* animation 1 has finished, so you don't need to worry about allowing for the duration of animation 1 when delaying animation 2.